# JPA 2 different native queries with same class as entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am new to JPA. Currently I am writing a native query with `@Query` annotation. I have a class similar to the below

```java
@Column(name="field1")
Private String field1;

@Column(name="field2")
Private String field2;

@Column(name="field3")
Private String field3;
```

I am writing 2 queries where 1 query has field 2 included in select projection and other does not include field 2. How can I use same class for both of the queries? I tried `@Transient` annotation. But it made values of both queries as null.

Answer (score 0):

You have lot of options to do that.

**Option 1 : Projections from Spring Data JPA without @Query**

```
interface MyProjection{
    String getField1();
    String getField3();
}
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Integer> {

    List<MyProjection> findAll();
}
```

**Option 2 : Projections from Spring Data JPA with @Query (quite similar to Option 1)**

```
interface MyProjection{
    String getField1();
    String getField3();
}
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT p FROM Entity p")
    List<MyProjection> customFindEntity();
}
```

**Option 3 : Projections from Spring Data JPA with @Query  without any interface**

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT p.field1,  p.field2 FROM Entity p")
    List<Object> customFindEntity();
}
```

**Option 4 : Projections from Spring Data JPA with @Query an native query (quite similar to Option 2)**

```
interface MyProjection{
    String getField1();
    String getField3();
}
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT field1, field3 FROM Entity p", nativeQuery = true)
    List<MyProjection> customFindEntity();
}
```

**Option 5 : Use Native query and return list of object array**

You have to extract your data from the list of array.

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT field1, field3 FROM Entity p", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Object[]> customFindEntity();
}
```